# Decimal issues in a data table in RenderTable Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, shinydashboard

I build a data table and rounded the values to two decimals, the result is good in R :

[image]

But in my shiny app, there were zeros added :

[image]

I would like to remove these zeros but I didn't find how..

Thank you a lot,

Elise

Answer (score 1):

You can use `formatRound` function.

```
library(DT)
datatable(df) %>% formatRound(c("a", "b"), digits=2)
```

replace `c("a", "b")` with the actual column names in your data.